# How to implement slack Oauth-2.0 in react js?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, slack

I need to implement slack authorization in my project for sending message in channel,Direct message and add reminder .So can anyone suggest me how to implement slack authorization in react project or is there any npm package that i can utilize to implement slack authorization like google authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I had the this problem. Took me ages to solve but anyway here is my solution:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      const getdata = async (con) =>{
            try{
            await axios.get("https://slack.com/api/users.identity",con).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err))
            }
           catch{

            }
        }

        const gettoken =  async () => {
            try{
              await axios.get("https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access",{params: {client_id: sclientId, client_secret: sclientsecret, code: name1[1]}}).then((res) => setData(res.data.authed_user.access_token)).catch((err) => console.log(err));
            }catch
            {

            }   
          }

        gettoken();

        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${ data}`,
                "token": data
              },
        };

        getdata(config);
    })
```

so `sclientid`,`sclientsecret`, and `name1`(which stores code) were variables I defined in my code. I had a link(or button) that redirects the user to slack for authorization . code below:

```
    <a href ={`https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?user_scope=identity.basic,identity.email,identity.avatar&client_id=${sclientId}`} ><img src="https://api.slack.com/img/sign_in_with_slack.png" /></a>
```

after the user has given permission then he is directed back to my site with a code. i used `window.location.search` to get the code out of the url and store it in `name1[1]` and then using that my `gettoken` function sends the client_id,client_secret and code to slack with a get request. this brings back  json which includes the token. I then send this token back to slack as a header in a request using my `getdata` function which returns the user info. To get the `client_id` ,`client_secret` and set the redirect url you have to go to [apps.slack.com](https://apps.slack.com) and create an app. Ask me any questions if this is not clear enough

Comment: Please reformat the code so it is readable